# Multiple outbound TCP connections from JBoss EAP to different IPs

Tags: tcp, jboss, jca

I'm working on application running on JBossEAP 6.4 in domain mode. I need to handle multiple (up to 1000) parallel TCP connections from server to different hardware devices.
Connections have to be opened at server side and will be keept up to 90 seconds. All connections uses the same port and protocol, but destination IP adresses are different..

I wonder if JCA adapter is suitable for this use case. Should I create special Activation specification for every single device or use something else than JCA resource adapter?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old, but JCA is a not-that-popular technology so some knowledge about it would be useful despite of the fact you might have been implemented all the things already.

Firstly, JCA is a spec for writing your connector, it's not a connector implementation itself. If you need your application to work with external TCP it's up to you to implement a connector.

Whether JCA is suitable for your particular needs depends solely on the nature of your "different hardware devices". Resource adapters has been designed to be used on per-service basis with possible connections pooling. I.e. all the connections this particular adapter would fire should have quite similar nature and be interchangeable. However, JCA adapters also have sensible advantages outside of this scope, especially in EJB environment. EJB imposes quite harsh restrictions upon your code: no locking, threads spawning, etc. It might be quite difficult to implement TCP I/O without all those things. Here comes JCA and it's threading freedom (MDBs are capable of providing EJB-friendly scope on their activation despite of an underlying thread source).

In conclusion: you should consider using JCA for TCP networking if you're working in EJB environment (or if you're going to do so in observable future). If you're using Spring-powered environment upon Java EE stack it may worth to omit such a complicated technology and stick to some pure Netty networking.

If you choose to proceed with JCA, consider inspecting the JCA [SocketConnector](https://jtalk.me/home/projects.xhtml?project=socket-connector) I am currently maintaining. It's build upon Netty stack and it could be a good start for you. You can also use it as a source of ideas how to build your own implementation instead.